# Filling/Populating a multidimensional array,, with elements of another array, and adding/incrementing values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

In `Ruby` I have a multidimensional array, 4D;

```
choices[ii][jj][kk][ll].
```

I have another array;

```
data[kk][ll]
choices[ii][jj].size==data.size
choices[ii][jj][kk].size==data[kk].size
```

I would like to populate the last two dimensions of choices with the elements of data, as they are the same size I am looking for an approach which requires little code.

In MATLAB I know how to do this easily with subscript indexing; eg. `choices[ii,jj,:,:]=data[:,:]`. As well, in MATLAB I can add the matrix/2Darray easily.

How can this be done in Ruby?

EDIT: **an example**

```
bb=Array.new(2,4)
aa=Array.new(3,Array.new(2,0))
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
irb(main):006:0> aa[1]=bb
 => [4, 4]
irb(main):007:0> aa
=> [[0, 0], [4, 4], [0, 0]]
```

This is ok, but for a 3D array, I get the array 'bb' copied into sections I don't want it to:

```
aa=Array.new(3,Array.new(2,Array.new(2,0)))
=> [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
irb(main):013:0> aa[2][1]=bb
=> [4, 4]
irb(main):014:0> aa
=> [[[0, 0], [4, 4]], [[0, 0], [4, 4]], [[0, 0], [4, 4]]]
```

Comment: I think this is what you want. `choices[ii][jj][kk] = data[kk]`

Comment: @Santosh, thanks but for some reason the 'data[kk]' seems to be added in places I would not expect...

Comment: aa=Array.new(3,Array.new(2,Array.new(3,Array.new(2,0))))
=> [[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]]
irb(main):027:0> aa[1][1]=bb[0]
=> [4, 4]
irb(main):028:0> aa
=> [[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [4, 4]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [4, 4]], [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [4, 4]]]

Comment: Give us a small data set example, along with your expected output, and an example of the code you've written toward solving this.

Comment: @theTinMan, added an example. could you shed some light on it?

Comment: From code review I found a post telling a C++ programmer not to use the techniques of building arrays with 2 arguments with mutable values. " As a guide line you should never use the 2-argument version of Array.new with a mutable value as its argument. Use the block-version instead." from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10551

Comment: there is this way "x, y = 2, 3  #you get these values from the user
m = []  #initializing m for scope reasons
x.times { m << Array.new( y ) }  # adding new arrays to m" from here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/141223

Answer (score 0):

I read the [documentation on Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html) more carefully.

*An array can also be created by explicitly calling ::new with zero, one (the initial size of the Array) or two arguments (the initial size and a default object).*

```
ary = Array.new    #=> []
Array.new(3)       #=> [nil, nil, nil]
Array.new(3, true) #=> [true, true, true]
```

*Note that the second argument populates the array with references to the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as Symbols, numbers, true or false.*

*To create an array with separate objects a block can be passed instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as hashes, strings or other arrays:*

```
Array.new(4) { Hash.new } #=> [{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

*This is also a quick way to build up multi-dimensional arrays:*

```
 empty_table = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
 #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

Which means that I was modifying the element which was referenced in multiple places. And I had to explicitly create a new Array object for each entry along the new dimensions I was adding, so in a way building the extra dimension incrementally. There seem to be multiple ways of doing this. One is this method of a block sent to Array, and another is to do an iterator on the dimension and make a new Array for each entry.

I also found this [post](http://ruby.about.com/od/Writing-a-2048-Clone-in-Ruby/fl/Two-Dimensional-Arrays-in-Ruby.htm) which highlights the problem in very simple terms:>>

*The wrong way, and the way I see people trying often is to say Array.new( 4, Array.new(4, 0) ). In other words, an array of 4 rows, each row being an array of 4 zeroes. And this appears to work at first. However, run the following code:*

```
 a = Array.new( 4, Array.new(4, 0) ) a[0][0] = 1 pp a
```

*It looks simple. Make a 4x4 array of zeroes, set the top-left element to 1. But print it and we get…*

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

*It set the entire first column to 1, what gives? When we made the arrays, the inner-most call to Array.new gets called first, making a single row. A single reference to this row is then duplicated 4 times to fill the outer-most array. Each row is then referencing the same array. Change one, change them all.*

*Instead of passing a value to the Array.new method, we pass a block. The block is executed every time the Array.new method needs a new value. So if you were to say Array.new(5) { gets.chomp }, Ruby will stop and ask for input 5 times. So all we need to do is just create a new array inside this block. So we end up with Array.new(4) { Array.new(4,0) }. Now let's try that test case again.*

```
 a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4, 0) } a[0][0] = 1 pp a
```

*And it does just as you'd expect.*

```
 [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```